# The longest that I have ever been in London is/was

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> The longest that I have ever been in London **is** 28 days.

vs

> The longest that I have ever been in London **was** 28 days.

Could anybody please tell me which one is correct? 
*Is* or *was*?

Comment: you are missing what it was you did in London, which may affect the answer. As 'stayed' was past tense but 'lived' is a much more complicated tense and could be is or was (but I am not honestly sure).

Comment: Your sentence is missing the lexical verb.  **have** is an auxiliary verb in the sentence you're trying to make.  But both **is** and **was** would be idiomatic there.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, both are correct, but they do have different meaning.

If 28 days is still your record for longest stay in London, you would be correct to say:

> The longest that I have ever been in London **is** 28 days.

But if you were *in* London and had just beaten that record by staying longer than 28 days you would be right so speak of the previous record in the past tense:

> The longest that I have ever been in London **was** 28 days.

However, you may also speak of it in the past tense if you are no longer visiting London and so will never exceed that record - but in such an instance you might be better phrasing it as:

> The longest I ever stayed in London was 28 days.